# Camera2 preview does not go fullscreen

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I am struggeling with a problem related to get the camera2 go fullscreen on a surfaceview. It does fill the whole height of the surfaceview, but when it comes to the width I face problems (plese see image attached below).

My layout file look like this:

```
<android.view.SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</android.view.SurfaceView>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:hint="Brukernavn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Passord"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />
```

In the surfaceCreated method I run the following code in order to set the desired size of the Surfaceview

```
Size[] size = strem_conf.getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder.class); 
 ((SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview)).getHolder().setFixedSize(size[0].
getWidth(),size[0].getHeight());
```

[image]

Thanks for any help or guidance!

EDIT: It seems to work great in landscape mode, so the problem seems to occour in portrait mode.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am also looking for an answer to this issue.

Comment: @zeeshan I don't remember what the result turned out to be, sorry. But I think I just might have used in landscape mode since that seemed to work ok for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I fixed using a different theme for my application than the default one.
On AndroidManifest.xml I added:

```
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">`
```

and on styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```